# ¿Como utilizar correctamente la función .load?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Quiero utilizar la función `.load` en mi servidor `ISS`.

Este es el código utilizado

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo básico AJAX Jquery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cargar() {
            $('#caja').load('texto.txt');
            console.log(document.getElementById('caja').value);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="cargar()">Cargar tiempo</a>
    <div style="width:400px;height:400px; position:relative;" id="caja">
        Aqui se cargaran los textos desde AJAX
    </div>
    <script>
     console.log(document.getElementById('caja').value);</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Al hacer click en el `<a>`, no me cambia el valor del `div` por el de `texto.txt` que tengo, y en la segunda console.log me aparece que el valor que tienen el div es indefinido,

¿no me debería mostrar la string?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) de `jQuery` sirve para:

> Cargar datos del servidor y colocar el HTML devuelto en los elementos coincidentes.

Los párametros que reciben son:

> ```
> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
> ```
>
> **url**: Una cadena que contiene la URL a la que se envía la solicitud.
>    **data**: Un objeto o cadena simple que se envía al servidor con la solicitud.
>   **complete**: Una función de devolución de llamada que se ejecuta cuando se completa la solicitud. Los parámetros de esta son `function (String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)`

Una solución para tu caso podría ser:

```
    function cargar() {
      $('#caja').load('texto.txt', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
```

#### Demo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function cargar() {
    $('#caja').load('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/master/LICENSE.txt', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="cargar()">Cargar tiempo</a>
<div style="width:400px;height:400px; position:relative;" id="caja">
  Aqui se cargaran los textos desde AJAX
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Marcos, pero así unicamente hago que console.log me marque una cadena vacía, y no que salga el texto que tengo situado en mi texto.txt.

Comment: @JesusSanchez, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, al actualizarla me he dado cuenta que no tenía bien la url, muchas gracias Marcos. Un saludo!